# What if I set the constraint weight to zero in OptaPlanner?

Tags: optaplanner

If I set the weight of a constraint to zero, does that mean that this constraint does not take effect? look like below:

```
@ConstraintWeight("Speaker conflict")
private HardMediumSoftScore speakerConflict = HardMediumSoftScore.ofHard(0);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deactivating optaplanner rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492946/deactivating-optaplanner-rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally: **yes, the constraint has no score impact so is effectively ignored.**

Implementation wise:

- In DRL score calculation in 7.20.0.Final that constraint rule still eats CPU power because Drools doesn't support disabling rules after building the KieBase at the moment.
- In the ConstraintStreams prototype (long-term work in progress, not yet released) that constraint already automatically takes no CPU power because it isn't be added to the KieBase.

Comment: Got it, Thanks, Geoffrey.